# Entity Framework with Oracle, NUMBER(10) Error

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

Im using Entity Framework 6.1.3 and an Oracle database. I have a number(10) field in the database which is automatically mapped to int32. But this field can have a maximum value of 9.999.999.999, which is to large for an int32. Therefore I added my own mapping in the app.config:

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
   <version number="*">
     <edmMappings>
       <edmNumberMapping>
         <add NETType="int64" MinPrecision="10" MaxPrecision="19" DBType="Number" />
       </edmNumberMapping>
     </edmMappings>
     <dataSources>
       <dataSource alias="SampleDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL))) " />
     </dataSources>
   </version>
```

But since I did this I get an exception as soon as the first operation using EF is executed:

```
An unhandled exception of type '...' occurred in DataAccessLayer.dll

Additional information: Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 

Model.PatModel.msl(2778,12) : error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 'Edm.Int64[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=]' of member 'MIN_OUTPUTQUANTITY' in type '...' is not compatible with 'OracleEFProvider.number[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,Precision=10,Scale=0]' of member 'MIN_OUTPUTQUANTITY' in type '...'.

Model.PatModel.msl(2784,12) : error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 'Edm.Int64[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=]' of member 'MAX_OUTPUTQUANTITY' in type '...' is not compatible with 'OracleEFProvider.number[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,Precision=10,Scale=0]' of member 'MAX_OUTPUTQUANTITY' in type '...'.
```

What can I do to use a NUMBER(10) as Int64/long?

Answer (score 0):

Your (and mine) issue is numbers between 2.147.483.647 and 9.999.999.999 do not fit into the standard int32 mapping.

I added this line to App.config and regenerated all from the edmx:

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <edmMappings>
        <edmNumberMapping>
          ...
          <add DBType="Number" NETType="int64" MinPrecision="10" MaxPrecision="10" />
        </edmNumberMapping>
      </edmMappings>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```